# How to keep an image open in OpenCV even if u press a key

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, opengl

How I do it? In matplotlib we have Show with False argument you can keep the image without closing. In my script, I pop out two images with cv2.imshow and I read that I can keep them up with waitKey(0), but when I press a key, they dissapear as the waitKey stablishs.

I want to know if there is a equivalent method for OpenCV as Show(False) from matplotlib.pyplot.

Comment: while (true): imshow and waitKey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use waitKey(number), you are setting a timer for how long OpenCV should wait for any key to be pressed and will halt execution during that time until either a key is pressed or the timer is up. When you set number = 0, this is shorthand for saying wait forever until a key is pressed.

```
key = cv2.waitKey(0)
if key == 27:
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The above code sets it so that when you press a key, it returns the key that you pressed to the variable: key. Now if key = 27 (i.e. the esacpe key has been pressed), then it will close the window. If not, then it will not. More details can be seen in the link below!

[OpenCV Images](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html)

Cheers,

warning: if you are using a 64-bit machine, then you need to use

```
k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop:

```
while cv2.waitKey(0) != 27:
    pass
```

The loop waits until Escape key is pressed.
Put it at the end of the script, because it's blocking the execution.